# CDK/Cloudformation - Unable to deploy stack because of Lambda Version deleted manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have one CDK stack with Lambda, its versions and Alias pointing to the latest version. In my CDK code, I am following this approach:

1. Create Lambda
2. Create a Version
3. Create an Alias pointing to the version.

With time, I had too many versions published, so I deleted the initial versions because of Lambda Storage limits. But the physical id of the initial version is still referenced in the CloudFormation Stack.
[Cloudformation stack creates resource success when tried the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygosE.png)

I don't have version 7 as seen in the above screenshot. Now, I am on version 22
[Current version of my Lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJi3h.png)

When I go and deploy my code, I get the below error because version 7 of Lambda is not there anymore

[Error that I get while updating stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy19E.png)

Any idea, how can I fix this without deleting the Lambda and creating this again?

My CDK Code:

```
final Function function = Function.Builder.create(construct, InfraConstants.WEBHOOK_RECEIVER_LAMBDA)
        .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_11)
        .handler("com.org.test")
        .memorySize(1024)
        .timeout(Duration.seconds(100))
        .functionName(InfraConstants.WEBHOOK_RECEIVER_LAMBDA)
        .code(Code.fromAsset("src/main/resources/sample-java.jar"))
        .tracing(Tracing.PASS_THROUGH)
        .layers(layers)
        .environment(LambdaUtils.getEnvVariablesWebhookReceiver())
        .build();
LambdaUtils.enableSnapStart(function);
return function;
```

```
public Version createVersion(Construct construct, String versionId, IFunction lambdaFunction) {
    return Version.Builder.create(construct, versionId)
            .lambda(lambdaFunction)
            .build();
}

public Alias createAlias(Construct construct, String aliasId, Version version, String alias){
    return Alias.Builder.create(construct, aliasId)
            .aliasName(alias)
            .version(version)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Are you able to just delete the stack and deploy it?

Comment: I would be able to but unfortunately, I can't. I can even delete this particular Lambda also....but wanted to check if there is any way to to get away with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of redeploy the lambda is change the CloudFormation ID of the resources.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid this is to ensure that the logical 'id' of the Version is updated when you want to publish a new one. When you delete old versions then it will no longer be referenced in CloudFormation.

If you compute the hash of the .java/.pom files inside of the maven project containing the lambda code and use that as an ID, it will publish a new version each time you make changes to your lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to redeploy and fix the issue would be to change any environment variable in the CDK package which will re-trigger the deployment.